# Rails ActiveRecord#create won't save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issues getting ActiveRecord to save to my postgres database. When I run the #create command on my class in pry (console debugger), I get a the newly created class instance back and it's auto-incrementing the ID. However, it's not in the database. No errors are thrown in the postgres logs, despite tweaking all postgres log settings to be as verbose as possible. If #create fails validation I will see an error in the postgres logs. However, a successful #create statement simply isn't saving to the database. I am on a Mac and installed postgres via brew.

Any ideas of what might be going on? This is driving me nuts and I've been at it all morning.

Update #1: I'm not using database_cleaner or anything similar.

Update #2: My pry console isn't showing any SQL, pass or fail. Here's what it looks like:

```
[26] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Tweet>)> Tweet.create({tweet_id: rand(111111111111111111..999999999999999999), author: 'adfsadfs', tweet: 'adfadfs', retweet_count: 3, latitude: 87.684, longitude: 41.364, tweet_created_at: Time.now})
=> #<Tweet:0x007fb408f2f210
 id: 64,
 tweet_id: 855873080844717219,
 author: "adfsadfs",
 tweet: "adfadfs",
 retweet_count: 3,
 latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fb408f2e2c0,'0.87684E2',18(45)>,
 longitude: #<BigDecimal:7fb408f2df78,'0.41364E2',18(45)>,
 created_at: Thu, 25 Jun 2015 14:08:33 CDT -05:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 25 Jun 2015 14:08:33 CDT -05:00,
 tweet_created_at: Thu, 25 Jun 2015 14:08:33 CDT -05:00>
```

Update #3: I'm running pry in the middle of my rspec test. The entirety of my rspec file looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Tweet, type: :model do
  it { binding.pry }
  pending
end
```

SOLVED: The issue is that I when the rspec test is cancelled prematurely or is marked pending, then the record isn't stored in the database.

Comment: The console should output the SQL it's executing. And overall, the console's output would be helpful.

Comment: Updated my original post with pry console output. No SQL gets shown, only the ActiveRecord object that is returned.

Comment: Huh... I've seen such behavior in `production` environment. Maybe it's just in a different database?

Comment: I have been checking all 3 databases (test, production, development) just to be sure, but nothing is showing up anywhere. It should be using the test database. It was working at one point and I'm not sure why it stopped working.

Comment: Can you retrieve that object later via `find`? It gets the `id`, it shouldn't if it fails to save.

Comment: Do `create!` for the backtrace.

Comment: Yes, I can find the record using #find.

Comment: It must be saving to an entirely different instance of postgres I guess? But it's strange - when I shut down postgres it stops working.

Comment: Then it is actually saved. Question is -- where? Oh wait, `test` environment? Tests, AFAIK, are run in a transaction, so after a full test run the state is rolled back to what it was before launch.

Comment: ... Then look in the database.yml file for the details, and make sure you're in the environment you think you are. If you're in test you're probably rolling things back.

Comment: Check out `log/test.log` and see if there is a `ROLLBACK` SQL statement somewhere at the end.

Comment: I tried using #create! but it didn't give me any additional information. I've done my best DD to ensure I'm in the right environment and I believe I am. I have Navicat (a Postgres client) open and using the exact same settings as what's in my database.yml file.

Here's the strangest part... when I execute "lunchy stop postgres", I can still keep using #create without error. However, once I cancel out of pry and relaunch my rspec script, then it says it cannot connect to the database.

Comment: Per I in ACID, which means Isolation, you will not detect any changes from an uncommited transaction with any external client. That is, if your test environment runs all tests in a giant transaction that gets rolled back at the end.

Comment: I would run `rails console` and do the `Tweet.create({tweet_id: rand(111111111111111111..999999999999999999), author: 'adfsadfs', tweet: 'adfadfs', retweet_count: 3, latitude: 87.684, longitude: 41.364, tweet_created_at: Time.now})` from there. Then make sure you can do a `Twee.find(...)` to find it, and then `exit1 the console, and check the database directly (make sure it's the right database per `config/database.yml`). If you find it, then there's something else going on in your code you aren't showing here that is causing the problem.

Comment: OK, checking out `log/test.log` does show the actual SQL being generated but there's no ROLLBACK involved. It's just a SAVEPOINT command followed by RELEASE SAVEPOINT.

The weird thing I'm dealing with now is that when I boot up my Mac I can connect to Postgres no problem. Then when I use `lunchy` to stop/start the service again, I can no longer connect to it. I use `lunchy` to stop/start the service again and now I can connect no problem.

Comment: Some success! The #create command works when using `rails c`. So, why doesn't it work when I use `binding.pry` in the middle of my rspec test?

Comment: `RELEASE SAVEPOINT`? Well, that's in the middle of the transaction, is was cut abruptly and therefore not committed. Did you exit your test suite abnormally, like via `exit!` or something like `kill ruby`? If so, that explains what's going on.

Comment: @D-side I updated my original post showing where I'm running pry in my rspec test.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, I'm asking how you exited your `pry` session :)

Comment: @D-side Oh, sorry. I'm just force-quitting out of pry via Ctrl-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such a thing as a [**transaction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) that comes with [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guarantees in PostgreSQL. Once you are in a transaction, you're pretty much "in your own world". You **and only you** can make changes and see them applied, no other observer will see these changes.

For others to see what changes you have applied, the transaction has to be **committed**, otherwise all changes will be lost. If app decides to issue a `ROLLBACK`, as in case of a failure (validation, exception, whatever), these changes are lost. If the connection goes down, these changes are lost. If the process dies, these changes are lost.

**Test suites typically run in a huge transaction.** After the test suite completes, `ROLLBACK` is issued and database becomes the same as it was before tests were run. This way a test run leaves no trace in the database's data: the code may have been bad and/or broken and that could affect further test runs. For that to **not** happen, test suite runs in a transaction. The downside of that: changes cannot be observed from the outside.

When in a `pry` session, use ActiveRecord's methods. Since it's running over the connection that's making a transaction, it is able to see the state built up to that moment.